# PHP: is eval the same as <?php ?>

Tags: php

The title says it all...

**Edit: the question is also meant as an query if both is based on `zend_eval_string`**

Does eval do the same as

```
<?php ?>
```

I always wondered how this can be intepreted . I tried to look it up , but no luck. And when I searched around the web I couldn 't find any articles that explained exactly how it works.

So again with markup, the question is:

```
  eval();
```

the same as

```
  <?php 

  ?>
```

**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

But using `eval()` opens up injection attacks:

```php
<?php
eval('echo "'.$_GET['text'].'"; ');
?>
```

Similar to SQL injection, the user can enter

```
a"; unlink('index.php'); //
```

or something even *more* nefarious:

```
a"; system('rm -rf /'); //
```

to delete index.php.

Otherwise, it's the same. **Don't use `eval()` unless you are absolutely sure that the user cannot complete a statement!**

If you want to execute a function whose name is given as `string` or load an attribute from an object given the attribute name as a `string`, you can do it without `eval()`:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    function __construct() {
        echo __CLASS__." is being created!\n";
    }
    function __destruct() {
        echo __CLASS__.' under destruction...';
    }
    public $a = 3;
    public function hello() {
        echo 'hello'."\n";
    }
}
function sayBye() {
    echo 'bye'."\n";
}

$string = 'sayBye';
$string(); // executes sayBye
$obj = new myClass();
$prop = 'b';
$obj->$prop(); // calls $obj->hello()
$prop = 'a';
echo $obj->$prop; // 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, so both work with `zend_eval_string`? Cuz i work on an encryption extension for PHP basicly the code is preloaded and then gets parsed via `zend_eval_string`

Answer (score 2):

The `eval` is used to execute PHP code from a *String*.

If you are talking about use `<?php` tag, you already wrote the code, but with `eval` you can execute code from a variable, or a generated dynamic code.

> The most important thing is: You **never** should use the `eval` function with a user input! This is a critical security issue.

For example, the following code:

```php
<?php
function test() {
  echo "Hi";
}

test();
?>
```

will produce the same result as:

```php
<?php
$script  = 'function test() {';
$script .= '  echo "Hi";';
$script .= '}';
$script .= 'test();';

eval($script);
```

or:

```php
<?php
eval('
function test() {
  echo "Hi";
}

test();
');
```

Comment: Thank you cery much for your answer, so `<?php ?>` isnt based on `zend_eval_string` ?